# How does Google Analytics proxy detection work?

Tags: google-analytics, proxy, traffic

I hosted a website and included a Google Analytic tag in it to count the visitors. The website itself is kinda empty and has no purpose other than trying out Google Analytics.

It seems like Google Analytics can somehow find out if i visit the website via a proxy and doesnt add this visit to the visitorcount. It doesnt matter if i use the proxy directly in the browser or via a java framework like HtmlUnit or Selenium.
The frameworks and proxys themself are working, i checked it at websites like whatismyip dot com. The Analytic tag is also working, since it correctly adds normal visitors to the visitorcount.

So my question is: how does Google Analytic find out someone is using a proxy? As far as i know the only indications someone is using a proxy are in the HTTP-Headers (X-Forwarded-For tag and so on). But the JavaScript which is included in my site shouldnt have access to the HTTP-Request, right?

I used free proxys which can be found if you google "free http proxy list" or similar keywords. Does Analytic automaticly downloads and blacklists those IP-Adresses? Because i canot imagine any other way it can find out someone is using a proxy just via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you tick "Exclude bot" in View settings it may be that Analytics recognizes those IPs as spam sources. Since these proxies are free services they can be used frequently for this purpose by malicious people and Google has blacklisted them.